# How Do I Merge Three Columns From A Csv File To Give Me A Single Column With Php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am importing a CSV file that has 3 adjacent columns lets call them Size, Color and Item. I need to combine these columns and have one long column that has all these value WHILST stripping out the rows that have a no content in them.

I am still having trouble combining the two thus far.

Have tried array_merge and so forth but i get no love.

```
$a = array($data[4]);
$b = array($data[5]);
$result = array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b);
print_r($result);
```

with `$data[4]` and `$data[5]` being the csv columns

my result is:

```
Array (
    [0] => Size
    [1] => Colour
)
Array (
    [0] => Large
    [1] => Black
)
Array (
    [0] => Medium
    [1] => Black
)
Array (
    [0] => Small
    [1] => Black
)
Array (
    [0] => Extra Small
    [1] => Black
)
Array (
    [0] => Large
    [1] => White
)
Array (
    [0] => Medium
    [1] => White
)
Array (
    [0] => Small
    [1] => White
)
Array (
    [0] => Extra Small
    [1] => White
)
Array (
    [0] => 
    [1] =>
)
```

I would like something like

```
Array (
    [0] => Size
    [1] => Large
    [2] => Medium
    [3] => Small
    [4] => Extra Small
    [5] => Black
    [6] => Black
    etc....
)
```

Comment: What are the original arrays?

Comment: check what does it print `print_r($a)` and `print_r($b)`

Answer (score 0):

could you push the data onto the `$result` stack? e.g.

```
$result = array();
$result[] = $data[3];
$result[] = $data[4];
.. etc
```